# while loop will not stop after each input

Tags: java, while-loop

Ok guys, Im having a problem getting this while loop to stop. As long as I enter something it loops again.  Point of this program is to guess a random number, and if the guess is lower display " too low" and if higher than the random number display "too high" and give them 7 tries and kill the game if the make 7 tries or get it right. please help

My output

```
I'm thinking of a number between 1-100.  You have 7 guesses.
First guess: 
20
Sorry too low
Guess 1:
20
Guess 2:
20
Sorry, you didn't guess it in 7 tries.  You lose.
Sorry too low
Guess 3:
22
Guess 4:
2
Sorry, you didn't guess it in 7 tries.  You lose.
Sorry too low
Guess 5:
22
Guess 6:
2
Sorry too low
Guess 7:
2
Guess 8:
```

Output should be:

```
I'm thinking of a number between 1-100.  You have 7 guesses.
First guess: 1
Sorry, you are too low.
Guess # 2: 2
Sorry, you are too low.
Guess # 3: -8
Sorry, you are too low.
Guess # 4: 0
Sorry, you are too low.
Guess # 5: 7
Sorry, you are too low.
Guess # 6: 612
Sorry, that guess is too high.
Guess # 7: -523
Sorry, you didn't guess it in 7 tries.  You lose.
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class App1
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    int secretNumber = 1 + r.nextInt(100);
    int guesses;
    int tries = 0;

    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1-100.  You have 7        guesses.");
    System.out.println("First guess: ");
    guesses = keyboard.nextInt();
    tries++;


    while(guesses != secretNumber && guesses < secretNumber ){
        System.out.println("Sorry too low");
        System.out.println("Guess " + tries + ":");
        guesses = keyboard.nextInt();
        tries++;

    while(guesses != secretNumber && guesses > secretNumber )
        System.out.println("Sorry too high");
        System.out.println("Guess " + tries + ":");
        guesses = keyboard.nextInt();

        tries++;

    if (tries <7){
        System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't guess it in 7 tries.  You     lose.");
    }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `while(guesses != secretNumber && guesses > secretNumber )` is missing a `{`...but you really only need a single loop to do the whole thing

Comment: So many questions on SO can be solved by saying "what will the computer do" - and walking through it with a pencil and paper to find out. If that is too hard, add some prints to see where you code gets to and what the variables are at that point. Better yet - invest in the time to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: `if (tries <7){..` ? you probably meant: `if (tries > 7){` and add a `break` statement there, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn more on the scoping and program flow. However, good attempt. The following code will fix your code.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    int secretNumber = 1 + r.nextInt(100);
    int guesses = 0;
    int tries = 0;

    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1-100.  You have 7        guesses.");
    while(guesses != secretNumber && tries < 7) {
        System.out.println("Guess #"+tries+": ");
        guesses = keyboard.nextInt();
        if(guesses == secretNumber) {
            System.out.println("You win");
            break;
        } else if(guesses < secretNumber) {
            System.out.println("Sorry too low");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry too high");
        }
        tries++;
        if(tries >= 7) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't guess it in 7 tries.  You lose.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a single while loop, and check the input using if statements, something like this:

```
while(guesses != secretNumber){   
  if(guesses != secretNumber && guesses < secretNumber ){
    System.out.println("Sorry too low");
    System.out.println("Guess " + tries + ":");
    guesses = keyboard.nextInt();
    tries++;}

  else if(guesses != secretNumber && guesses > secretNumber ){
    System.out.println("Sorry too high");
    System.out.println("Guess " + tries + ":");
    guesses = keyboard.nextInt();
    tries++;}

  if (tries <7){
    System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't guess it in 7 tries.  You     lose.");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing a lot of things including a check for the correct answer. My answer is simply a copy/paste of your code. You need another if statment to check for the correct answer then use `break;`. You may find the answers by MadProgrammer or ferdinand-neman far more helpful in adding the missing code

Comment: I figured it out thanks and I added the correct answer line, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this, you need to ask the user for value, you need to compare that against a known/random value and display some message if it's not equal.  You increment the number of tries and check to see if they have exceeded the available number of tries...

Something like...

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Random r = new Random();

int secretNumber = 1 + r.nextInt(100);
int guess = 0;
int tries = 0;
System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1-100.");
do {
    System.out.println("You have " + (7 - tries) + " remaining");   
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (guess < secretNumber) {
        System.out.println("To low");
    } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
        System.out.println("To high");
    }
    tries++;
} while (guess != secretNumber && tries < 7);

if (guess == secretNumber) {
    System.out.println("You guessed right, well done");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you loose");
}
```

for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to only execute code a certain number of times.

```
for (int guessNum = 1; guessNum < 8; guessNum++)
    // do stuff
```

The above code will be run 7 times, and the variable `guessNum` will hold your "guess number". If you would like to end the loop before 7 guesses have passed, you can use the `break` statement in the body of the `for` loop. So if the user doesn't guess right, the loop continues. If they do, you "break" out of the loop and the guessing ends.

Here's my rendition, just for completeness:

```
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rng = new Random();

int secretNumber = 1 + rng.nextInt(100);
System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1-100.");

boolean success = false;
for (int guessNum = 1; guessNum < 8; guessNum++) {
    System.out.println("Guess #" + guessNum + ". You have " + (7 - guessNum + 1) + " attempts remaining.");
    int guess = cin.nextInt();
    if (guess < secretNumber) {
        System.out.println("Too low!");
    } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
        System.out.println("Too high!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You guessed right! Have a cookie!");
        success = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!success)
    System.out.println("Better luck next time.");

cin.close();
```

Comment: @John3136 I started the counter at one because `i` represents the guess number. The first guess isn't guess `0`, it's guess `#1`. I suppose you could just add one to `i` when you print the string, but I think starting the counter at one keeps the meaning better.

Comment: @ParkerHoyes Interesting can of worms! In this case it really doesn't matter and you are probably right. Perhaps rename `i` to `guessNumber` and it's clear. More generally, when people see loops in C/C++/Java, they expect them to go from 0 to < n, so by going 1 to n you are breaking convention. As soon a bug occurs because of it, you'll get blamed for "doing it wrong" because "your code is different".